# gradle nod set up fails installing node x86_64

Tags: node.js, gradle, gradle-node-plugin

I'm using gradle node plugin for my project and when I run the `nodeSetup` task it tries to install the node dist from https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.6.0/node-v12.6.0-darwin-x86_64.tar.gz which I know does not exists. The correct URL should be https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.6.0/node-v12.6.0-darwin-x64.tar.gz I'm not sure why its adding `x86_64` instead of `x64` and I was wondering if there is any way to directly specify the complete dist URL for gradle node plugin.

Here is my node config inside my build.gradle

```
node {
    version = '12.6.0'
    npmVersion = '6.0.0'
    yarnVersion = '1.13.0'
    download = true

    workDir = file("${buildDepsDir}/nodejs")
    npmWorkDir = file("${buildDepsDir}/npm")
    yarnWorkDir = file("${buildDepsDir}/yarn")
    nodeModulesDir = file("${project.projectDir}")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be using an old version of the plugin, [this exact issue](https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin/commit/ac3f280cc36798ce26446db2974728f7854dc59e) has been fixed in [3.2.1](https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin/releases/tag/3.2.1)